# == vs equals vs XOR benchmark

Tags: java, string-comparison, xor

I was doing a benchmark to find out which of `==`,`equals` and `^ (XOR)` could be potentially faster while comparing Objects. for this purpose I wrote this program, and got the following results:

First Iteration:

```
equals  took : 345
==  took : 625
xor  took : 284
```

Second Iteration:

```
equals  took : 346
==  took : 182
xor  took : 254
```

total after 100 iterations:

```
average equals:  305
average ==:  164
average XOR:  246
```

I have couple of questions here:

1. using `equals` method is faster than using hashCode() for the first time but using hashcode becomes faster after the second iteration. so is it safe to say if
   I'm using the same dataset over time to do some calculation its
   faster to use `hashCode()` rather than `equals()`?
2. after checking `String.hashCode()` implementation I know why `hashCode()` becomes faster for the second time, but why  `XOR` gets faster? I can't see any logic for that.

here is the program just for refrence:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

    String[] set1=new String[10000000];
    String[] set2=new String[10000000];
    Random r=new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++){
        int next=r.nextInt(1000);
        set1[i]=next+"";
        set2[i]=next+"";
    }


    for(int q=0;q<2;q++){  // change 2 to another number for more iterations
        long start0=System.currentTimeMillis();
        int equals0=0;
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            for(int j=set2.length-1;j>=0;j--){
                if(set1[i].equals(set2[j])){
                    equals0++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("equals  took : " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start0));


        long start1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        int equals1=0;
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            for(int j=set2.length-1;j>=0;j--){
                if(set1[i].hashCode()==set2[j].hashCode()){
                    equals1++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("==  took : " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start1));



        int equals2=0;
        long start2=System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            for(int j=set2.length-1;j>=0;j--){
                if((set1[i].hashCode() ^ set2[j].hashCode())==0){
                    equals2++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("xor  took : " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start2));

    }
```

EDIT: 
After running the program running for 100 iterations, I realized only the last iteration would speed up using XOR . Still and I'm not quite sure what's so special about last iteration?

Comment: Hashcodes are not unique.

Comment: you should in general run you tests several times (e.g.100) and average the results. It can always happen that the OS or the JVM kicks inbetween and messes up you timings

Comment: Next to that your test is flawed as you are running all the tests in the same run and reusing state. Regarding the fact that xor is faster it used hashCodes as they become faster the xor becomes faster... For these kind of benchmarks you want to use something like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: @Westranger I have run it many times mate, obviously I couldn't print out the output for 100. it was just a sample .

Comment: @SLaks oh, I thought hashCode for an unmodifiable string is unique, as it gave me right results.

Comment: @nafas - no hashcodes can't be unique because there are only 2^32 -1 possible values but more than that possible number of Strings.  Also String caches the hashcode after it's been computed which is why it is faster after it's been computed once.

Comment: @nafas pls update you question with the average values to get rid of glitches in your measurement. And the XOR timing should not change over time

Comment: Do not even assume String hashCodes are anywhere collision free even for *short* Strings, for example: "Aa".hashCode() == "BB".hashCode() !

Comment: @Durandal I guess ur right mate, but my assumption was the chance of two hashcode to be same is very low,

Comment: in the last loop you are using only the XOR method , so it being cached by the jvm and respectively cached by the processor so after some time , the jvm can understand the usage of the methods and try to prevent errors

Comment: @AntJavaDev why is that only happening on the last iteration, everything is the same from 0 to 99th iteration then on the last one this optimaztion pops up

Comment: The first and last iteration of a loop are often treated specially when the JIT compiles the code to machine code - the technique is called *loop peeling*, the idea is to check invariants which can not lead to an exceptional state in the loop, if they do not occur in the first iteration. So its quite possible the JIT generated 2 or 3 versions of your q-loop body with very different machine code.

Answer (score 2):

Since the only way to compare objects for equality is to use equals() the question is moot, the only alternative that *may* be applicable depending on circumstances and use-case is identity comparison (==).

But identity comparison and equality are *not the same concept*, so you need to carefully decide which one is the right tool for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a [look into the implementations](http://%20http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java/?v=source) of the two mehtods

**hashCode()**

When looking at the implementation of the Hashcode function we can see that is is dependant on the String length, which influences the time needed for computing the hash code. This explains why in your case it is sometimes faster. Anyway this method is not suited to compare very long String of different lengths, because the has value is limited to 32bit. It can happen that two differne (very long) Strings have the same has value. The hashCode() method also only does pure math to compute the hashvalue.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

**equals()**

When looking at the implementation of equals, we can also see that this one is length dependant. But unlike the hasCode() implementation does this method quit the loop at the moment when the Strings are not equal. This could make the comparison faster in some occasions. The hashcode method is always computed for the whole String. The equals method has an if statement in it's while loop, which makes the computation slower than the hashCode() loop.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = count;
            if (n == anotherString.count) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = offset;
                int j = anotherString.offset;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**XOR**

The only explanation why the `XOR` part is slower that your `==` part is that the logic-expressions differ. The `==` expression is `A == B` where the XOR one is `(A XOR B) == 0`. But I'm not totally sure with this one because the timing difference is almost 50%.
In the end you `XOR` comparision is useless,because it also calls the hashCode() methods like you `==` implemenation does, in which the most time is spend.

you should stick to the equals method which ist the only reliable approach here.